# sorting array by part of array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, printing

I have an Object array like this

```
Football[] FootballTeam = new Football[4];
```

> ```
>  FootballTeam[i] = new Football(ranked, names, played, w, d, l, GF, GA, GD,points);
>  FootballTeam[0] = 0  Real Madrid 3   2   0   1   7:6 1   5
>  FootballTeam[1] = 1  Barcelona   3   0   0   3   4:9 -5  1
>  FootballTeam[2] = 2  Valencia    3   1   0   2   7:7 0   5
>  FootballTeam[3] = 3  Atletico Madrid 3   3   0   0   9:5 4   7
> ```

how can I sort this list by point and average(GD) or How can I print in order sorted by score and average? . I can delete "ranked".

Comment: It looks like you have 3 different arrays. Which one of them do you want to sort, and how do they relate to each other?

Comment: sorry about that, i edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Arrays.sort method, from `java.util.Arrays` class, by passing in a  "comparator" object. The comparator should compare the attributes you want to sort by.

Assuming your `Football` class has methods that return the "points" and "GD", this will sort the teams by points, and the teams that have the same point count are sorted by "GD".

```
Arrays.sort(FootballTeam, Comparator.comparing(Football::getPoint)
                                    .thenComparing(Football::getGD));
```

Comment: that's incredible. Actually, I wanted the high score to be first, but if I print the list in reverse, it will not be a problem. thank you so much.              
Arrays.sort(FootballTeam, Comparator.comparing(Football::getPoint).reserved() is worked.

Comment: Yes the `Comparator` interface has utility methods for lots of things, like reversing the order